# list operation using function in python

Tags: python

Ask the  user for which team member to assign task and assign it, display the output as team member name and task assigned
Is there any solution using without For and While loop?.
Please let me know if there is any solution.

```py
Member = ["Gahininath", "Vighnesh", "Bhargav", "Amit", "Rahul"]
def myfunction(Member):
    User_Input_Member = input('enter member name')
    if User_Input_Member in Member:
        for i in Member:
            if i==User_Input_Member:
                y = input('Enter Task what you want tparticularpmember memeber')
                res = i + ' ' + y
                x = ':'
                print(res + x + 'Task assign successfully to the member')

count=input('How many member you wnat to select to assign task today')
y=int(count)
i=1
final_list=[]
while y >= i:
    myfunction(Member)
    i=i+1
print('Here is your final  memeber list with their task ')
print(final_list)
```

Output:

`['Amit will solve 1st problem', 'Rahul will solve 2nd problem','Rohit will solve 3rd problem']`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same basic outcome without a `for` or `while` loop using recursion - example below. However so long as you want the process to repeat a certain number of times, you're looping - the only difference between my approach below and a `for` or `while` loop is the manner in which the same process is repeated.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Define a list of team members
members = ["Gahininath", "Vighnesh", "Bhargav", "Amit", "Rahul"]

# Create a function that accepts a list of team members, and optionally
# a pre-populated "final_list", and then asks the user what tasks to assign, 
# and whether they are finished or not. 

def myfunction(members, final_list = None):
    if final_list is None:
        final_list = defaultdict(lambda: [])
    member = input('Pick a team member: ')
    if member not in members:
        print ('That is not a valid team member.')
    else:
        task = input('What would you like them to do? ')
        if task:
            final_list[member].append(task)
        else:
            print ('No task entered.')
    another = input('Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)')
    if another.lower() == 'y':
        return myfunction(members, final_list)
    else:
        print (f'Here is your final list of members and their tasks: {list(final_list.items())}')
        return final_list

# call the above function, saving the final_list to a new variable. 
final_list = myfunction(members)
```

**Some example runs:**

With a single member and task:

```
Pick a team member: Amit

What would you like them to do? draw

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)n
Here is your final list of members and their tasks: [('Amit', ['draw'])]
```

With two members and tasks:

```
Pick a team member: Amit

What would you like them to do? draw

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)y

Pick a team member: Vighnesh

What would you like them to do? fly

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)n
Here is your final list of members and their tasks: [('Amit', ['draw']), ('Vighnesh', ['fly'])]
```

With three members and tasks, but the second name entered is not in the list of members:

```
Pick a team member: Amit

What would you like them to do? draw

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)y

Pick a team member: notaname
That is not a valid team member.

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)y

Pick a team member: Vighnesh

What would you like them to do? fly

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)n
Here is your final list of members and their tasks: [('Amit', ['draw']), ('Vighnesh', ['fly'])]
```

With one team member, but no task entered:

```
Pick a team member: Amit

What would you like them to do? 
No task entered.

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)
Here is your final list of members and their tasks: []
```

Finally with three team members, but two of them are the same:

```
Pick a team member: Amit

What would you like them to do? draw

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)y

Pick a team member: Amit

What would you like them to do? fly

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)y

Pick a team member: Vighnesh

What would you like them to do? cycle

Would you like to assign another task? (y/n)n
Here is your final list of members and their tasks: [('Amit', ['draw', 'fly']), ('Vighnesh', ['cycle'])]
```

So this seems to do what you want, without a `for` or `while` loop in sight - but computationally there's no difference between using a `while` or `for` loop and doing what you're doing here - in fact the above approach may be more locally memory intensive if you have a very long lists of tasks.

Comment: Hello Vin Thank you for giving an alternate sol for the problem its appreciable.

Comment: But it can possible we can do this  problem only using the List operation or Dictionary operation what we have in python

Comment: Hi @AmitKumar, Can you expand on what you mean by "list operation" and "dict operation"?

Comment: You're looking for a way to repeat a certain operation an undetermined number of times (i.e. determined based on the user's requirements, which are arbitrary and unknown). There's no way to "pre-program" this - it must be iterative. The only choice is whether you iterate with, say, `for` or `while`, or whether you make iteration recursive as proposed here. It's not an issue of syntax, but of what you're fundamentally trying to do - Python cannot know what your user wants - your user has to tell the program, repetitively (i.e. **iteratively**).

Comment: Hello @Vin Thank you for your input, yes I understand we have to use Iteration either in form of a loop or Recursion to repeat things